# Check if a point is within a quadric

Tags: geometry, quadrics

I have a [quadric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric) surface, that is defined like this:
$$0 = Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy+ Exz + Fyz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J$$

How can i check if a point is inside of the quadric or on which side of the surface it is.

I figured out that for spheres or cylinders solving the following equation worked. The sign of $q$ tells me if the point is "inside" the quadric or not

$$q = Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy+ Exz + Fyz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J$$

Is this true for all quadrics?

Comment: How do you know which signs indicate interior and exterior even in the simple case of a sphere? Both $x^2+y^2+z^2-4=0$ and $4-x^2-y^2-z^2=0$ describe the same sphere.

Comment: I think the problem will be more meaningful if it asks to determine whether two given points are separated by the surface.

Comment: Some surfaces, such as hyperbolic,  do not have an inside.

Answer (score 1):

For brevity, let $Q(x,y,z)=Ax^2 + By^2 + Cz^2 + Dxy+ Exz + Fyz + Gx + Hy + Iz + J$.  (The letter $Q$ by itself will refer to the quadric defined by $Q(x,y,z)=0$)

Then $Q(x,y,z)=0$ and $-Q(x,y,z)=0$ both define the same quadric.  So simply checking the sign of $Q(x,y,z)$ won't tell you whether the point is inside or outside the conic).

What is inside/outside for a quadric anyway?  For ellipsoids it sounds straightforward, but what about hyperboloids?

A reasonable definition of "outside" is "where the tangents are" or, put another way, all the points that are on a tangent to the conic.

For a point $P$ all tangents from $P$ to $Q$ contact $Q$ on a plane $p$ that is called the polar of of $P$ wrt to $Q$.  If $p$ intersects $Q$, the tangents are real, otherwise they are imaginary.

So $P$ is outside $Q$ if $p$ intersects with $Q$. This is easily computed.  If you need more detail, just ask,